# Rotation of a point around origin in 2D converge to 0

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, trigonometry

Following code is written to rotate a point around the origin in 2D. However, instead of going on a circle, it keeps converging to the centre. (originally ran on Three.js) This code works absolutely correct. (I have done this in other platforms and even ran a numerical simulation in excel sheet too).

Why does this happen?

```
<body>
    <div id="vals"></div>
    <script>

        theta = Math.PI / 90.0;
        var x = 1;
        var y = 1;

        var element = document.getElementById("vals");

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            var r = Math.sqrt( x * x + y * y );
            var para = document.createElement("pre");
            var node = document.createTextNode("x="+x+"     y="+y+"     r="+r);
            para.appendChild(node);
            element.appendChild(para);
            x = (x * Math.cos(theta)) - (y * Math.sin(theta));
            y = (y * Math.cos(theta)) + (x * Math.sin(theta));
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

p.s.
I know that if I normalize the values and multiply by the magnitude , I would get the correct answer. However I want to know why this exact thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you apply **changed** x value to get y. It is just wrong. Instead remember old value and use it.

```
     var tempx = x;
     x = (x * Math.cos(theta)) - (y * Math.sin(theta));
     y = (y * Math.cos(theta)) + (tempx * Math.sin(theta));
```

Second: reusing the same values causes error accumulation, so radius might converge - exactly as you see. So more exact approach is to store initial values and rotate them using current angle (not angle difference)

```
    var x0 = 1;
    var y0 = 1;

        in the loop:
    x = (x0 * Math.cos(theta * i)) - (y0 * Math.sin(theta * i));
    y = (y0 * Math.cos(theta * i)) + (x0 * Math.sin(theta * i));
```

Comment: Oh, I was a complete idiot. Thank you very much for picking that out for me. :)